# Best way to load test application under same machine

Tags: performance, load-testing, gatling, siege

I've used Gatling and Siege to load test my application. However, at certain points (especially when my load is higher), I would get a lot of gateway and requestTimeoutException errors. Since the requests doesn't seems to even get to the app, I presume the issue is to be my IP address being blocked due to the influx of traffic from 1 IP address. How do you overcome this? I'm assuming that the users that Gatling and Siege create to send concurrent requests are all under the same IP of my machine?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible for Gatling, the [relevant feature request has been closed](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/2725), you might want to consider using [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) instead, JMeter's [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler has "Source IP" field where you can put the needed IP address or [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing)

[image]

More information: [Using IP Spoofing to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter/)

Comment: I followed your link, that feature request was closed with a commit that completes it, by making `localAddress` a dynamic value.